# how to add shapes in word document using apache poi library

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf, xwpf, hssf

I need to add below shapes available in MS word using Apache poi library.

I am not able to find any specific class/method available for word to add such shapes.

However, I can find some method to add shapes in excel from apache.

```
 XSSFDrawing patriarch= (XSSFDrawing) sheet3.createDrawingPatriarch();
 XSSFClientAnchor regionr = patriarch.createAnchor(0, 0, 1, 1, (short)6, 12, (short)8.95, 12);
 XSSFSimpleShape region1Shapevr = patriarch.createSimpleShape(regionr);
 region1Shapevr.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.LINE);
```

Can you please suggest if there is any similar class/method available or other approach to add shapes as well in word document.

Comment: Hi @Arvind, did you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302326/apache-poi-xwpf-adding-shapes-to-header)

Comment: Yes Sridhar, I have tried it  but it din't work. I want to add ShapeType.CALLOUT_1 https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/sl/usermodel/ShapeType.html

Comment: share the code snippet you tried with, so that we can try to fix from there.

Comment: for (XWPFParagraph p : doc.getParagraphs()) {
List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
for (XWPFRun r : runs) {
CTGroup ctGroup = CTGroup.Factory.newInstance();
CTShape ctShape = ctGroup.addNewShape();
ctGroup = CTGroup.Factory.newInstance();
ctShape = ctGroup.addNewShape();
ctShape.setStyle("width:80pt;height:24pt");
ctShape.setStyle("width:80pt;height:24pt");  
Node ctGroupNode = ctGroup.getDomNode(); 
CTPicture ctPicture = CTPicture.Factory.parse(ctGroupNode);
CTR cTR = r.getCTR();
cTR.addNewPict();
cTR.setPictArray(0, ctPicture);
r.addTab();
}}}

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: This is not a duplicate but instead it is to broad to answer. My example is only for creating text box shapes but not for creating shapes in general. Creating general `Word` shapes is not supported by neither the low level `ooxml-schemas` nor `apache poi`. It would only be possible by manipulating the `XML` directly on very low level base.

Comment: @AxelRichter Sorry to ask you simple question , how to manipulate the XML using XWPFRun? Any example?

Comment: @Arvind: `XWPFRun` provides `getCTR()` which returns a `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTR` which extends `org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject`. But as said this is to broad for a question here. So ask a new question which is more special. For example "How to create a callout shape in Word using apache poi?" Do describing exactly what you have tried already (for example how you have created a textbox shape) providing a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And at best do providing a screenshot how this shall look like in `Word`.

Comment: Thanks @AxelRichter!! your previous answer was very useful for me in other term.!!! I will do ask the new question as per your suggestion.